# Docker, can't ssh to rhel/centos container on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, docker

I've been chasing this for almost a week and can't get it working. I've got Docker 1.0.1 installed on my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop. When I launch a rhel/fedora/centos container and install sshd, I can't establish an ssh connection. Doing the same with a Ubuntu container works fine.

Here is the debug output of my ssh attempts:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 4022.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/mb/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/mb/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: put_host_port: [localhost]:4022
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "[localhost]:4022" from file "/home/mb/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 0 keys
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<3072<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
```

I've read countless posts regarding adjustments to the ssh_config (ciphers and MAC) and sshd_config (UsePam=no) but none of those have helped a thing.

Lastly, the interesting thing is that I am **not** receiving the usual warning on first connection that the
*RSA key fingerprint is wh:at:ev:er:wh:at:ev:er:wh:at:ev:er.*
*Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?*

Command used to start centos container:
docker run -i -t -p 14022:22 centos:6 /bin/bash

Command used to start sshd:
/usr/sbin/sshd -D -o UseDNS=no -o UsePAM=no -o PasswordAuthentication=yes -o UsePrivilegeSeparation=no -o PidFile=/tmp/sshd.pid

Command used to connect to container:
ssh mb@localhost -p 14022

Comment: Maybe compare your attempts to [this Dockerfile for SSHing into CentOS](https://gist.github.com/Mulkave/10559775) and see what it's doing differently.

Comment: Exact same deal:  
_$ ssh localhost -p 8022_ returns "Connection closed by 127.0.0.1". It almost feels like a firewalling issue, except that it works with Ubuntu images and ssh debug shows successful handshakes.

Comment: Another test shows that Docker on rhel 6.5 (same Centos container) works fine. Seems only my Ubuntu Docker hosts (one laptop, one desktop) have the connectivity issues, and only when connecting to rhel/centos images. Frustrating.

Comment: Man, this is frustrating. Using the Dockerfile @jwodder pointed to, I cannot ssh in when the service is started through _supervisord_. If I stop sshd with _supervisorctl_ but start it by using _/usr/sbin/sshd -D_ at the command prompt, ssh = success?!? The command executed by _supervisord_ is the exact same as the one I use. Both executed as root.

Answer (score 0):

Only valid answer I could come up with: replaced Ubuntu docker machine with Centos 7. All is well.